# Capacitor for spot welding

Tags: capacitor, short-circuit, supercapacitor

I've seen a video where the guy make a spot-welder using capacitors
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1SMUFSiaV-8
AFAIK shorting capacitor is harmful. The question is:
Are there any caps that can provide a high enough current needed for spot-welding still being within spec? Right now 70C 6A LiPo battery + arduino spot welder that shorts the battery for 0.2sec works well for me but I'm thinking about PSU + capacitors for the same purpose. Maybe supercapacitors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Electrolytics would work well. A 300,000 µF 35 VDC electrolytic with screw terminals could store ~200 J [1/2 CV<sup>2</sup>], which might be enough to weld a small nickel tab, and a [scooter starter solenoid](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009T017P4) could probably handle that current.

Supercapacitors tend to have higher internal series resistance than a corresponding electrolytic. For example, this [1.6 F, 16 VDC supercap bank](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B07DFFB2HW) could theoretically store ~200 J, but on connecting to the low-impedance spot welder, most of the energy is lost heating the capacitors. Perhaps two or three of these banks might suffice. Another issue with supercaps is that an equalizing network is needed, and during heavy discharge, it might not be sufficient to prevent a weak capacitor from being reverse-charged beyond 2.75 V.